# How to add a line with this sign “|” in between every column in java program ? What is the logic for loop?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
System.out.println("EMPO"+"\t"+"ENAME"+"\t"+"SAL"+"\t"+"AVERAGE");
System.out.println("--------------------------------");
while(rs.next())
{
int eno=rs.getInt("empo");
String ename=rs.getString("ename");
int sal=rs.getInt("sal");
int avg=rs.getInt("average");
System.out.println(eno+"\t"+ename+"\t"+sal+"\t"+avg);
}
```

[![In between every column here .. like after EMPO there should be a partition like which should go like .. |
          |
          |
          | ...
This pattern . ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo13F.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo13F.jpg)

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @Sunil sir I dont have 10 reputation for posting another image

Comment: @Sunil but I just want a for() loop logic so that I can install that logic in my code.

Comment: Don't post image of code, click on "edit" on your question and add code as text.

Comment: This is about as much help as you will get without posting your attempt - [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5221149)

Comment: @Sunil here is the code sir

Comment: Sir please also explain for rows too , the one you left for me to practice , I tried for that , but im getting a exception in thread main in UnknownFormatConversionException , because i wrote - in sop(String.format(“%1$-15s”,eno)... ); , i guess i dont know the right prototype of this method ... so kindly please explain this one too . Thank you

Comment: And also please explain what is (%1$-15s) and (%1$15s) because these two things worked like magic... how they are working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple:
Let's assume your each column is 15 characters wide, if it's less or more change accordingly:

```
// Format header
System.out.println(String.format("%1$-15s", "EMPO" )+ "|"+"\t"+String.format("%1$-15s", "ENAME" )+ "|"+"\t"+String.format("%1$15s", "SAL" )+ "|"+"\t"+String.format("%1$15s", "AVERAGE" )+ "|");
```

Similarly format your row: I leave this one for you to practice.

```
System.out.println(eno+"\t"+ename+"\t"+sal+"\t"+avg);
```

If you are not able to figure out, let me know.

**Explanation:**

```
String.format("%1$-15s", "EMPO")
```

This is for strings. It will do right padding, to make it 15 characters. So if you string is less than 15 characters, it will append `' '` space characters. This is done to maintain column width on console output.

```
"|"
```

This is simple, it just adds pipe characters

```
String.format("%1$15s", "SAL" )
```

This one is for numbers, as numbers need to be right aligned.